# If data is in CSV format, does that mean it is inherently 'structured data'?

Tags: etl

I'm trying to think through an ETL process for some data which is likely going to be received from the data source in a CSV format.

If the data is to be consistently in a CSV format, that means it is 'structured' correct? Like I could import it straight into a database and essentially query it, right?

If that is the case where CSV files are structured data, then could I run Hive queries on it to do some transforming?

Are there any disadvantages of loading CSV files straight into a database, and then doing transformation like an ELT process?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure ELT concept really applies when speaking of reading CSV files from a Hive query. It is more like running the T and the L in a single INSERT-SELECT query, if the T is straightforward.

First define an EXTERNAL TABLE pointing to an empty HDFS directory. Then push your CSV file(s) in that directory. Now you can SELECT the file content *(providing that the table structure maps the actual CSV structure of course)*, transform data on-the-fly, and INSERT the result in a "managed" Hive table -- ORC, SequenceFile, AVRO, whatever.

Optionally you can JOIN other tables (lookups, deduplication, etc) but be aware that Hive optimizer is still very crude, don't expect fancy queries to perform well (nor all simple ones for that matter). Also expect some awkward bugs, and some nasty regressions on every upgrade.

But if your T requirements are really complex, and require multi-step processing with temp datasets, I would advise you to learn Pig scripting. With the HCatalog interface it can bulk-load Hive tables on the final stage.

~~

One last word: your "structured" CSV may contain nested "structured" fields such as Arrays, Structs, Arrays of Structs. Hive supports these complex data types.